# Solr result has not expected order

Tags: solr, solr4

I have several documents, that have a title:

1. -> "Just some Word 13 from year 2015"
2. -> "Just some Word 13 from year 2011"
3. -> "Just some Word 13 from year 2012"
4. -> "Just some Word 13 from year 2014"
5. -> "Just some Word 13 from year 2013"

When searching for 13 i'm expecting number 5 to be the first result because 13 is exists twice.

Field is multiValued="true".

My fieldtype for indexing looks like this:

```
<analyzer type="index">
   <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[(&quot;)(,:;!?)]" replacement=""/>
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30" side="front"/>
   <filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solr copyfield directive (indexing with and without EdgeNGramFilterFactory) was the solution to boost direct hits.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the document 5 doesn't really have twice `13` term. What you have is `13` and `2013` that is so different for search. In this case all the five documents have just one `13` term, so the order is not wrong. If you want solr consider `13` and `2013` the same term you can use synonyms. So put this line in your `synonyms.txt` file:

```
13, 2013
```

And include this filter in your `schema.xml` file:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

Now when you search for `13` the document 5 will have more relevancy than the others.

Comment: He is using `<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30" side="front"/>` to his schema, so when he build his index, he may have for doc 5: 13, [...], 13, 013, 2013